# How long does it take the xenomorph to build the hive?

Tags: alien-franchise, predator-series, alien-vs.-predator, alien-vs.-predator-requiem

I am curious how fast can a xenomorph build a hive? Does it only take 1 day? Let's take *Alien vs Predator: Requiem* for example. There is a scene that the hospital is target where the Predalien Queen starts to build her hive and create an army of xenomorphs.

It feels like it only takes a couple of hours to make the whole hospital become her hive. Isn't that too fast? I mean the structure is all basically from the xenomorph's gelatinous liquid, how fast they can produce those liquid? It's like every second they spit those liquid and create an hive...(*I can imagine it and the scene is so funny.)

Comment: Xenomorphs grow to full mature size in a matter of hours; so I guess their metabolism allows them to replenish the gooey thing to make hives real quickly